# NHibernate mapping with a class hierarchy whose base class is abstract and the discriminator is not a string

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, domain-driven-design

Here are the domain model classes:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
...
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
...
}
```

Note that the parent class is abstract and this is what gives me some difficulties when comes the time to map with fluent nhibernate. My discriminator is a byte (tinyint in the DB). Because it is not a string and I can't manage to set a discriminator value on the base class, this does not work (taken from the mapping class for BaseClass):

```
DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn<byte>("Type")
    .SubClass<ChildClass>()
    .IsIdentifiedBy((byte)OperationType.Plan)
    .MapSubClassColumns(p => { ... })
```

The error message I get is:

Class Initialization method UnitTest1.MyClassInitialize threw exception. NHibernate.MappingException:  NHibernate.MappingException: Could not format discriminator value to SQL string of entity BaseClass --->  System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format..

The following post seems to explain what happens. They give a solution with xml but not with fluent nhibernate: http://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=974225

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the solution with XML - exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found a workaround but this seems so like a patch...
I added the following to the mapping file:

```
SetAttribute("discriminator-value", "-1");
```

It seems to instruct FNH not to use a string (I think it uses the class name) for the abstract base class.
To make it work with the -1 value, I also changed my discriminator type from byte to sbyte.

**Edit:**
I missed that: this is the second parameter to DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn that takes the default value. So the correct answer to my question is:

```
DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn<sbyte>("Type", (sbyte)-1)
```

Comment: Much thanks - I was having a similar issue with the discriminator not being a string.